# Letters for complex numbers

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

Suppose that I am writing a proof or some other piece of mathematical writing, and wish to introduce $n$ distinct complex numbers, for some positive integer $n$.  What are the complex numbers called?

- If $n=1$, then clearly the (unique) complex number I am interested in is called $z$.
- If $n=2$, the two complex numbers are called $z$ and $w$.

It is the case $n\ge3$ that i am concerned about.  There seem to be no other standard letters for complex numbers, and all the other letters around that end of the alphabet ($x,y,u,v,t$ etc.) are reserved for real numbers.  Indeed we often write $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$ where $x,y,u,v$ are stipulated to be real.

What am I missing here?  I can't think of any way to get around this problem.  Is there a theorem in mathematics that states that every problem parametrized by $n$ complex numbers is equivalent (in some precise sense) to a problem involving just two complex numbers?

Comment: How about $z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots$?

Comment: $z_1$, $z_2$, $\dots$, $z_n$. But you can use whatever letter you want, so long as you tell what it means. There is no special relation between $x$, $y$ and $z$; you're free to say $z=a+ib$, why not?

Comment: As Abel says, just use indices. What would you do if you had an obscene number of real variables? What is special about complex variables?

Comment: This is either a joke that isn't very funny or you aren't ready for complex analysis.

Comment: @jwg Your comment isn't necessary: it doesn't answer the question, nor is it helpful in any way I can imagine.

Comment: This is a pretty bad question, so I downvoted - it should probably be closed. I will however point out that there are common Greek letters used for complex numbers, such as $\rho, \chi, \xi,\eta, \kappa$. In fact, $\rho=\sigma+it$ is an extremely common notation when working with the zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph of the question? Such a suggestion seems to be more humorous than serious...

Comment: @amWhy, I was explaining to the poster why I downvoted, as the site recommends. This may help him ask better questions in future.

Comment: @Donkey_2009. Did you think about using subscripts? Maybe you did, and you rejected the idea for some reason. If so, I'm interested to know why.

Comment: @jwg. I don't see any explanation of anything in your comment.

Comment: @bubba In the problem I was working on I already had two complex variables, called $z$ and $w$, and needed a third to use as a range of integration.  Calling that $z_1$ or something would be a bit strange.  I have since rewritten my proof so that the first variable I introduced was called $z_0$ since that makes a bit more sense.  Sorry for the slightly facetious question - I was genuinely intrigued by the fact that no letters other than $z$ and $w$ really seemed 'right' to be used for complex numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subscripts! 
$$
z_1 = x_1 + i y_1, \dots, z_n = x_n + i y_n
$$